# C# way to add value in a List<T> at index

Tags: c#, list, indexing, this, addition

Is there any way you can add a value at a specific index? I try to do indexator and I have Lists. Is there any trick for making this this in this context :D

```
 public class Multime<T>
{
    private List<Multime<T>> multiSets;
    private List<T> multimea;


    ***public Multime<T> this[int index]
    {
        get { return this.Multisets.ElementAt(index); }
        set { this.Multisets.CopyTo(value,index); }
    }***



    public List<Multime<T>> Multisets
    {
        get { return this.multiSets; }
        set { this.multiSets = value; }
    }//accesori Multimea de multimi

    public List<T> Multimea
    {
        get { return this.multimea; }
        set { this.multimea = value; }
    }//Accesori Multime
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the methods already provided by List?  There's a distinct possibility one does exactly what you need.

Comment: INSERT is not good :D, i dont want the rest of the list to be modified and i want to add/replace at index

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`List<T>.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx), perhaps?

But I'd suggest you probably just want to fetch/write - not insert:

```
public Multime<T> this[int index]
{
    get { return Multisets[index]; }
    set { Multisets[index] = value; }
}
```

Note that as of C# 3, there are simpler ways of writing those properties, btw:

```
public List<T> Multimea { get; set; }
public List<Multime<T>> Multisets { get; set; }
```

It's also not generally a good idea to actually expose composed collections directly - it means you have no control over what happens in those collections.

Comment: i think it moves element[index] to index+1 i dont want to affect the rest of the list,i need to replace just the object at index

Comment: @TyGerX: So you should have asked about *replacing*, not *adding*. See my edit.

Comment: set { Multisets[index] = value; } does not work i dont know why some compile error becouse Multisetst is List i think

Comment: @TyGerX: "some compile error" leaves a lot to be desired as descriptions go. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: @TyGerX That's not a compile time error...that's a runtime error.  And it's because you used an index that's outside of the valid range, i.e. accessing an item that doesn't exist.  The code listed here is fine.

Answer (score 94):

The `.Insert()` method on `List<T>` is exactly for this purpose:

```
someList.Insert(2, someValue);
```

This would modify the `someList` collection to insert `someValue` at index `2`, pushing other values up one index.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Can you use [List.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `List.Insert`

This should solve the problem you are having.

Answer (score -2):

You may be looking for something more like a Dictionary or Map. These are types of collections that allow you to assign an object using key value pairs so you can always assign an object at a certain position and retrieve it from that same position. You may think that you need the list because you don't know how many records you will store, but if you have some sense of the maximum number of records it will help you decide if you can use something like a Dictionary. The limit is pretty high I think, but you can look at the Dictionary class to see the limits.